# Outlook VSTO uninstall plugin

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm new with vsto. Is there a trigger to run when we call uninstall vsto plugin? I'm using plugin to add new category to outlook. So when I uninstall plugin I would like category to be deleted.

I managed to delete category on button click, but that's while plugin is installed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. It is a bad idea to do anything in Outlook from the installer. What if the user has multiple profiles? Do you connect to all of them? What if the profile is not cached and Outlook would prompt for credentials when opening a store?

If you uninstall Office, it does not wipe out your existing Outlook data. Not on the server, and not even locally - all your OST and PST files are still intact, and when you install Outlook again, you'd be able to use them.

Comment: Thanks man, I thought so, but wanted to be sure.